# How do I highlight the selected item (tab index location) in my windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to highlight the selected item on my page because it's busy and there is a lot going on. The user will not have access to their mouse, only keyboard so currently they tab through buttons quickly and enter in to what they need to do (it's a fast data entry sort of app if you must know).

I want to be able to highlight the selected button (so when you tab through currently it will select a button but it isn't very noticeable, it just has a slight border around it when selected).

I know that you can use a focusEnter and focusLeave event, but I would like to avoid that if at all possible just because there are so many buttons on the page that I would have to have a ton of repetitive events with almost the same code.

Comment: what is it exactly what you want?

Comment: You can and should use two __common__ event handlers for focusEnter and focusLeave events for all your buttons! use the (Button)sender param to access the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should use **just two common** event handlers for `Enter` and `Leave` events for all your buttons!

Use the `sender` param to access the buttons:

```
private void buttons_Leaveobject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    ((Button)sender).ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
}

private void buttons_Enter((object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).ForeColor = SystemColors.Control;
    ((Button)sender).BackColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
}
```

Use your own ideas about how to highlight the focussed button; this is a bit excessive imo..:
[image]

Of course Button with `FlatAppearance` can do the highlighting all by themselves as they have separate Colors for their states.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating your own class derived from `Button`, and then handling the background painting yourself.  That would allow you to play with the background look/color and/or the border effects.